# Save shapefile as SQL script with ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr

I have a some shapefiles and I want to convert them into SQL scripts. 
I know that ogr2ogr can put data into a database itself. But I want to have a SQL script which can be executed and put data to DB.

Any advice?

If it impossible with ogr2ogr maybe I can use other tools for this?

Comment: What kind of DB are you using ? PostGis ? Oracle Spatial ? Different DB's use different formats for e.g. geometries, projections etc.

Comment: It will used in Oracle.

Comment: Oracle Spatial then ?

Comment: Yeah, Oracle Spatial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way of generating an Oracle SQL dump in OGR. You could perhaps use the Python OGR/GDAL bindings an make a script that reads the shapefile(s), and writes Oracle SQL.

Otherwise, there is a [Comma Separated Value (.csv)](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html) driver, where you could "morph" the output into an Oracle bulk loader file, or an SQL script.

Alternatively there is a [PostGIS SQL dump driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgdump.html), the only SQL dump driver in OGR. Maybe you could alter the output to fit Oracle.

Oracle supports WKT geometries, and both drivers mentioned generates WKT on output.